# Where does the variable "name" come from?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

Sample Code:

```
from enum import Enum

class Countries(Enum):
  Afghanistan = 44
  Andorra=88
  Austrailia=38


print(Countries.Afghanistan.name)
```

output:Afghanistan

Question: Where is the variable "name" defined ? I couldn't locate in the source code of Enum which was very complicated anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum is a class in python for creating enumerations, which are a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, constant values. The members of an enumeration can be compared by these symbolic anmes, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over. An enum has the following characteristics.

- The enums are evaluatable string representation of an object also
  called repr().
- The name of the enum is displayed using ‘name’ keyword.
- Using type() we can check the enum types.

I hope this will be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

EnumMeta will use the names found in self._member_names as the enumeration member names. This defined values can be found at line 170 of enum.py.
But I could be wrong...